# High quality scaled <canvas> drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on 2d  and downscaling photos on it for upload. I draw them only using 90 degree steps.

What parameters affect drawImage() quality in different browsers? I'd like to sacrifice speed over quality when drawing the images, so that the quality of the output is maximized.

Any tricks with subpixel adjustments?

Any luck using webGL canvas and draw images there? Would it give more options for preserving image quality during scale?

Photos can be 2 mpix - 10 mpix range.

EDIT: Looks like it is not possible on webGL because texture sizes are limited to 512 x 512 or 2048 x 2048.

Comment: You have not described what your problem is that you need solved.

Comment: What parameters affect drawImage() quality in different browsers? <--- this is the question, ending with a question mark

Comment: WebGL textures are not limited to certain resolutions. Also, the parameters you pass to `drawImage()` won't affect the quality of the result so long as you provide integer coordinates. The various browsers have some special values you can adjust to change the algorithm used for resizing, but there's nothing offered by the canvas spec (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific? I'm not getting what exactly you want. 
But as long as drawImage is concerned you should go through [Mozilla Spec of `drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Slicing)